# Does this BIG monogdb storage cause low performance?

Tags: performance, mongodb

We have a mongodb with 336GB data on it.

Unfortunately there is only 8GB memory on that server.

Is it true to say that this will slow the db down, especially when I try to traverse the entire collection?

What can I do to improve performance?

Comment: If you've already got the database, and the server, have you tried it with your queries, compared to your performance requirements? The best answer is to try it and see if it meets your need before trying any special 'general' optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get things right, this isn't a "BIG" production setup; it is actually relatively small.

That aside:

> Is it true to say that this will slow the db down, especially when I try to traverse the entire collection?

It is true yes. As you iterate the collection MongoDB will need to page in your data, this is true even if you have indexes on the collection.

The exception to this is when you use `indexOnly` cursors whereby all the data comes only from the index, including the returned document; these are otherwise known as covered queries.

The problem you have here is that your dataset is 42x greater than your RAM amount, assuming you are allowed to use all your RAM (this is not true of course, the OS and other programs will reserve amounts off for themselves). This means that if you expect to iterate the entire collection you will not be able to do it performantly, instead MongoDB could be page thrashing its allocated memory.

> What can I do to improve performance?

Get a little more RAM.

You could also try a bit of sharding if getting too much RAM on that one server is a pain.

I would aim for about 20x more data than RAM, that shouldn't be too bad in most cases.

Comment: `that shouldn't be too bad in most cases` but bad for transverse , right?

Comment: @jackalope It dpeends solely upon what you expect out of MongoDB and what response times you expect, the OS should be able to page 20x without too much thrashing, fiar enough it wont be super dupa fast but it, in normal cases, is acceptable.

Comment: Okk, i'll do more research on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should index your collection http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/ to improve performance, but bear in mind that memory is utilised by mongodb when querying indexes so make sure each index you create can fit within the memory you have on your server.

You could also shard your collection but you will need more servers to do this. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/

And I know it's obvious but get more memory - its cheap!

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb uses memory-mapped files to map the data in to the systems virtual memory. If you try to access more data than the available memory of the system, the performance will be poor. You'll have to consider other options like sharding, indexing, increasing RAM etc. Indexing may improve the performance but not by much if done on a large data set, because indexes also need memory. A few references:

First 3 questions talk about memory-mapped files: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/

On sharding: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/

Ensuring index fit into the RAM: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#ensure-indexes-fit-ram

Comment: mmap maps to virtual memory not RAM

Answer (score 0):

The other answers say either "have enough memory to fit your data" or "have enough memory for each index" or "have some multiple of your RAM in data".   None of those are very effective nor very precise for capacity planning.

You need to know what your access patterns will be and then decide what indexes you will need to effectively be able to use your data.  If *all* of your indexes fit in available RAM with some room to spare for most recently touched documents, then you should be okay.

When your working set (accessed data + indexes) cannot fit in RAM then your performance will be correlated more with disk access speed than anything else.  Depending on how fast your disks are and on your throughput and latency requirements, it may work out okay or it may not.

While there is not enough information to say with certainty whether you will succeed or fail on this particular machine, you should be able to collect enough information to determine that for yourself by analyzing your indexing needs, etc.